# DispatcherTimer pauses when minimizing/maximizing/closing window

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to explain my problem on simple app:

I have MainWindow with just one TextBlock. Property Text of this TextBlock is binded to property Seconds of my class CTimer. In MainWindow I also have a DispatcherTimer doing one simple thing every second - increments Seconds property of my object.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Try.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="txtTime" Text="{Binding Seconds}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private CTimer timer = new CTimer();
    private DispatcherTimer ticker = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ticker.Tick += AddSeconds;
        ticker.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        txtTime.DataContext = timer;

        ticker.Start();
    }

    public void AddSeconds(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        timer.Seconds++;
    }
}
```

CTimer.cs:

```
public class CTimer:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int seconds = 0;

    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return seconds; }
        set 
        { 
            seconds = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Seconds");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My problem - when I press whichever of three window buttons (min/max/close) and keep it pressed, the DispatcherTimer pauses and stays paused until I release the pressed button.

Do somebody know the cause of this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you press one of these buttons, the UI-Thread is blocked. Because its a DispatcherTimer, it belongs to the Window's Dispatcher and runs in the same thread. So if this thread is blocked, the DispatcherTimer stops running.

You could use the `System.Timers.Timer`. The UI wont get updated as long as you hold one of the three window buttons, but the timer will keep running.

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.  DispatcherTimer can only fire its Tick event when the WPF dispatcher loop is executing.  It won't when Windows starts its own modal dispatcher loop, used for example when you resize the window.

There is no Timer class that is capable of giving you a callback that's guaranteed to run at the requested interval.  Including the asynchronous timers, which do a better job at it since they can fire the callback on a threadpool thread so are not subject to whatever is going on in the UI thread.  But that doesn't solve your problem either, you still need the dispatcher to invoke the UIElement update on the UI thread.

So the basic mistake is that you are relying on the DispatcherTimer to keep time.  It is not made for that.  Environment.TickCount and DateTime.UtcNow keep time.  Only use the DispatcherTimer to update the displayed value, calculate the actual value from one of these properties.

Comment: Thank you for answer, also helped me, especially to realize that DispatcherTimer would not be used with time counting

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simply because when clicking on the buttons, you are using the thread that the timer is running on and the thread can only do one thing at a time. Please take a look at the [`DispatcherTimer Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) page on MSDN for more information.

From the linked page:

> The DispatcherTimer is reevaluated at the top of every Dispatcher loop.
>
> Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs. This is because DispatcherTimer operations are placed on the Dispatcher queue like other operations. When the DispatcherTimer operation executes is dependent on the other jobs in the queue and their priorities.